# Find the limit without using Bernoulli$-$L'Hôpital rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How can I find this limit without using L'Hôpital rule $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin(5\sin(3\sin(2x)))}{x}}$$
I think let $u=5\sin(3\sin(2x))$ but I doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the series expansion $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O(x^{6}).$

Thus  $\sin(5\sin(3\sin(2)))=30x+O(x^3)$, so $$\frac{\sin(5\sin(3\sin(2x)))}{x}=30+O(x^2)$$ and now take the limit.

Comment: We just need first order expansion which indeed corresponds to using standard limits.

Comment: Yeah I just wrote more terms, fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\frac {\sin(5\sin(3\sin(2x)))}x = \frac {\sin(5\sin(3\sin(2x)))}{5\sin(3\sin(2x))} \times \frac {5\sin(3\sin(2x))} {3\sin(2x)} \times\frac {3\sin(2x)}x$$

Comment: @user Because OP is supposed to figure out the rest on their own

Comment: That's fine! Even if you really let a very small "rest"!